# SELECT with a WHERE clause which is stored as string in another table

Tags: mysql, string, where-clause

In MySQL, I'm trying to select rows from a table using a `WHERE` clause which is not fixed (known in advance), but instead is stored in another table and will be pulled from that other table at run-time.

Although seemingly similar questions already have been posted on Stackoverflow, there is none which exactly covers that problem.

What I'm trying to achieve is the following :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (SELECT user_condition FROM user_condition_table WHERE id = '1')
```

The subquery

```
SELECT user_condition FROM user_condition_table WHERE id = '1'
```

Would produce the string

> first_name like 'Br' and last_name like 'A%'

So the overall query would look like :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name like 'Br' and last_name like 'A%'
```

I guess the problem here is that the returned string from select is returned as string and not as an SQL statement.
Is there any way to make that work?

Comment: You need to learn about dynamic SQL.  You cannot do this in a simple `select`.

Comment: Why don't you simply do this in two steps? For instance in PHP you could first get the subquery result and with that build the main query.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I would like to keep this task automated inside Mysql without the need to use any coding language for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use Dynamic SQL --> [Prepare / Execute / Deallocate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) commands.

[Dynamic SQL](https://www.google.pl/search?q=dynamic%20sql)

> Dynamic SQL is a programming technique that enables you to build SQL
>   statements dynamically at runtime. You can create more general
>   purpose, flexible applications by using dynamic SQL because the full
>   text of a SQL statement may be unknown at compilation.

---

Simple [live example](http://rextester.com/YYHIQY58692)

```
DROP TABLE  IF exists Users;
CREATE TABLE USERS(
  first_name varchar(20),
  last_name varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO Users VALUES('Tom','Smile'),('Bob','Hamilton'),('Jane','Moon');

DROP TABLE  IF exists user_condition_table;
CREATE TABLE user_condition_table(
  id int,
  user_condition Varchar(100)
);


INSERT INTO User_condition_table 
VALUES(1, 'first_name like ''B%'' and last_name like ''H%''');
```

---

and the query:

```
SET @x = ( SELECT user_condition FROM user_condition_table WHERE id = '1');
SET @x = concat('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ', @x );
SELECT @x;

PREPARE stmt2 FROM @x;
EXECUTE stmt2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. I have never tried it because I did such things in application code until now. Nevertheless, I got interested in the subject and just came up with the following solution:

```
SELECT @cond := user_condition FROM user_condition_table WHERE (id = 1);
SELECT @sqlstring := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ', @cond);
PREPARE sqlquery FROM @sqlstring;
EXECUTE sqlquery;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE sqlquery;
```

Some remarks:

- It seems that you need to use session variables (denoted by the leading `@`).
- This is not a stored procedure; it is just some normal SQL statements which you can type directly from within MySQL client, for example.